# object can not move

Tags: transforms

I download this car model from web, I can select all and move it, but the seat can not be moved! I don't know why?
have checked the modifier and the constrain, nothing.
why???
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file to https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: Probably the seats have their transforms locked.  Type N to open the side panel with one of them selected and look at the location transform.  If the lock is "closed" click it to open it.

Comment: thanks, it is the reason.  this question can close. how can I close this question and mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: You can either write the answer yourself and accept it or @MartyFouts can.

Comment: ...or any other guy can write an answer ;)

Comment: I will write an answer.   Since you're apparently a new user to Blender StackExchange, you might want to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and perhaps accept my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The seats have their transforms locked. Type <kbd>N</kbd> to open the side panel with one of them selected and look at the location transform. If the lock is "closed" click it to open it.